# Part of a solution to a mathematical induction problem I don't understand

Tags: induction

There's a part in the solution that I can't understand, I think it's just something basic that I'm missing. In the solution it says:

$$T(k) \leq  2(c(k/2)^2 \log(k/2)) + k^2$$

Then it became

$$T(k) \leq ( ck^2 \log(k/2) ) / 2 + k^2$$

P.S: I forgot how to do StackExchange latex again, I am so sorry.

Comment: For future reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
T(k) &\leq 2(c(k/2)^2 \log(k/2)) + k^2\\
&= 2(c(k^2/4) \log(k/2)) + k^2\\
&= (c(k^2/2) \log(k/2)) + k^2\\
&= (ck^2 \log(k/2))/2 + k^2\\
\end{align}

Comment: Brilliant. This is the part of Math I suck the most.. I didn't see that square coming. Thanks, very much appreciated. :)